# iBeacon constraint to accept multiple major/minors

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, ibeacon

I followed an online tutorial and had the following code working fine in my project, it can detect an iBeacon with a specific uuid/major/minor and do some logic with it. I'm wondering if there is a way where I can accept multiple uuid's or multiple major/minors and pass them on to other functions? Here is the code I have so far:

```swift
class BeaconDetector: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    @Published var lastDistance = CLProximity.unknown
    
    override init(){
        super.init()
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus){
        if status == .authorizedAlways{
            if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self) {
                if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable(){
                    startScanning()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func startScanning(){
        let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6")!
        let constraint = CLBeaconIdentityConstraint(uuid: uuid, major: 0, minor: 0)
        let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(beaconIdentityConstraint: constraint, identifier: "MyBeacon")
        locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
        locationManager?.startRangingBeacons(satisfying: constraint)
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRange beacons: [CLBeacon], satisfying beaconConstraint: CLBeaconIdentityConstraint) {
        if let beacon = beacons.first{
            update(distance: beacon.proximity)
        } else{
            update(distance: .unknown)
        }
    }
    
    func update(distance: CLProximity) {
        lastDistance = distance
    }
    
}
```

I think I know how to pass the values by just adding it to the update function, but how would I be able to detect and accept multiple beacons would be the biggest question I have right now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up location monitoring in the location manager for up to 20 regions. Those regions can either be GPS based geofence regions or "Beacon regions", or any mix of the two, but you are limited to 20. To register multiple beacon regions, you'd just call your `locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)` code more than once.

When you create beacon regions you must specify a UUID. You can make it a specific UUID and wildcard major/minor, A specific UUID and major and wildcard minor, or specific values for UUID, major, and minor ID. (I don't remember if you can specify UUID and minor and have it work for any major. It's been a while.)

If you use a wildcard for major or minor ID, the system treats any device that matches as being part of the same region, and you have to write code that figures out which specific beacon was detected. I seem to remember that once you've entered a region with a wildcard (say a specific UUID and any major or minor) then you won't get new "entered region" notifications if a second beacon with a different major/minor is detected. That’s treated as part of the same region. In that case you need to start listening to specific beacon notifications and look at the values you get for each one.